# integrity constraint violated - child record found exception

Tags: php, oracle, exception, error-handling

I want to show an alert (Im sorry but this type cannot be deleted) message in my website when i get an error ORA-02292: integrity constraint violated - child record found. How can I create that exception? From php or from the database and how exactly ?

I tried something like this

```
begin
  -- Test statements here   
        DELETE FROM PETTYPE
        WHERE PET_TYPE_CODE = 40;
        COMMIT; 
EXCEPTION 
       WHEN CHILD_RECORD_FOUND  
       THEN Dbms_Output.put_line('ERROR'); 


end;
```

But it doesn't work because child_record_found is not declared.

Any suggestions would be appreciated ! :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use when others,

```
create table ref1 ( a int primary key);
create table ref2 (a int references ref1(a));

SQL> select * from ref1;

         A
----------
         1
         2

SQL> select * from ref2;

         A
----------
         1
         2

set serveroutput on

SQL>    declare
  2     begin
  3    -- Test statements here
  4          DELETE FROM REF1
  5          WHERE a = 1;
  6          COMMIT;
  7  EXCEPTION
  8         WHEN others then
  9          Dbms_Output.put_line('Im sorry but this type cannot be deleted');
 10
 11
 12  end;
 13  /
Im sorry but this type cannot be deleted

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

Answer (score 0):

You can associate your own exception type with an internal Oracle error number using the PRAGMA EXCEPTION_INIT declaration.  Documentation: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/errors.htm#BABGIIBI